# Running ios ocunit logic tests through command line fails to access keychain

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ocunit, sentestingkit

I am trying to run my logic tests (**OCUnit**) using command line. but it fails with errors.

Command used

```
xcodebuild -sdk iphonesimulator4.3 -configuration Debug -project XYZ.xcodeproj -target XYZ build
```

Error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Couldn't add the Keychain Item.'
```

I want the simulator to run when I am running the project through command line so that it can access keychain. Or is there any other way to access keychain when it runs the proj through command line ?
Please help !!!

Comment: Any idea ? i am still stuck :(